# Paypal subscription next payment date

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

How can I get the next payment date from the IPN notification from Paypal. Is there a parameter there relevant? I found "next_payment_date" but it's not clear.
Right now, I'm just calculating it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculating it yourself is good, because PayPal some times skips sending an IPN.  It doesn't happen often, I've done tens of thousands of transactions and I've only seen this less than 5 times.

PayPal should send a subscr_eot when the subscription stops.

If you're on the standard payment, you'll never see next_payment_date
https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/ipn/pdt/nextpaymentdate-will-not-show

Also, if you accept echeques (payments via bank account), the payment won't always happen on that date, some times a week or more afterwards.